# How can we show $2g-2=deg(K_s+C)_{|C}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ $\subset$ $S$ be a smooth algebraic curve of genus $g$ in a smooth algebraic surface.

$K_S$ is the canonical divisor of $S$.

How can we show $2g-2=deg(K_s+C)_{|C}$ ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to do these computations in terms of sheaves but you can also do them in terms of divisors of course. By the adjunction formula we have $\left. \omega_S \otimes \mathscr{O}_S(C)\right|_C \cong \omega_C$. Hence we get 
$$\text{deg}(\left. \omega_S \otimes \mathscr{O}_S(C)\right|_C) = \text{deg}(\omega_C) = \chi(\omega_C) - \chi(\mathscr{O}_C)$$ by Riemann-Roch. Using the definition of the Euler characteristic plus Serre duality now gives
\begin{align*}
\chi(\omega_C) - \chi(\mathscr{O}_C) &= h^0(\omega_C) - h^1(\omega_C) - (h^0(\mathscr{O}_C) - h^1(\mathscr{O}_C)) \\ &= h^1(\mathscr{O}_C) - h^0(\mathscr{O}_C) - (h^0(\mathscr{O}_C) - h^1(\mathscr{O}_C)) \\ &= 2h^1(\mathscr{O}_C) - 2 h^0(\mathscr{O}_C) \\ &= 2g-2.
\end{align*}